# Embarking on a Schengen-bound flight on the night before my visa is valid

Tags: visas, schengen

I have my visa to a Schengen country from 20th October(Thursday), so I'm booking a flight with a transit at Abu Dhabi airport.

Would it be fine to board the plane on 19th Octobers at 22:00, or I can pass through immigration in India only if the Schengen visa is valid?

Comment: I called the airlines and they said I wouldn't be allowed to board the plane if the visa is invalid the day i board.

Comment: @user52486 That airline is retarded. They should only care about the arrival time in the Schengen area. And Indian immigration should only care about your papers for entering/exiting India

Comment: I just don't want any troubles at the airport, not sure where to confirm this.

Comment: that's a difficult issue: as Crazy says, the airline is stupid.  But then, *airlines are stupid*.  I would do this: phone the airline again and ask for a supervisor, explain clearly WHEN YOU WILL ARRIVE.  (Do NOT mention the transit airport, it is irrelevant.)  Explain that another staff member said you would not be allowed to board, get the opinion of a supervisor.

Comment: Hi @user52486 - in this question you need to click edit and delete all reference to the transit airport as it is totally irrelevant.  Please state exactly the arrival city, and arrival time/date as given on your ticketing.  Let's hear it!

Comment: Did you explain your exact situation to the airline?  Meaning the visa will be valid on arrival?  It's very easy to only hear 'not valid yet' but miss the point that it will become valid.  Maybe the agent simply misunderstood and is not stupid.

Comment: I also had to endure this stupidity of an airline. Visa started on 10, 6 hour flight boards at 11:55pm. I am at check in counter at 9pm. Lady said, you can't board, ur visa starts tomorrow. I asked for supervisor. He saw visa, and said, sorry for inconvenience, please proceed to board..

Comment: @DavChana collectively, then, the airline was not very stupid. You were allowed to board, after all.